# Write new file by matching strings from input file

Tags: python, regex, string, scripting

I have a few naive questions about scripting with Python.

I have some input files of the form

```
"{1,g,{Frog,12}}",(x**2+.7*x)/2**x
"{2,{g,h},{Pig,17}}",(.8*x**3-1.3*x)/2.5**x
```

etc., where the the first and last elements of the first column are always integers, the second element of the first column can be a string or a list, the third element of the first column is a string, and the second column is a function of a new variable.

I want to create an output file that takes every line and writes to a new file in the following form:

```
    if newstr==1gCow82:
        return eval((.2*x**2+x-.3)/1.8**x)
    elif newstr==1gFrog12:
        return eval((x**2+.7*x)/2**x)
    elif newstr==2ghPig17:
        return eval((.8*x**3-1.3*x)/2.5**x)
```

(to which I will prepend something like

```
 def bignewfunction(a,b,c,d,x):
 newstr="".join(str(a),b,c,str(d))
```

manually).

I don't think this should be that hard, but it will probably require some regex machinery which I haven't been able to absorb (e.g., how to convert the string "{a1,b1,{c1,d1}}" to a string with no quotes, brackets, or commas) and also some file creation in Python which I don't know. Alternately, it would probably be easier if I could remove the brackets and quotes from the first column of the input file, but that also requires similar scripting skills that I presently lack.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit** Edited to include more specific examples of how the input file may look.

Comment: Provide some examples of input file which contain all data types you mentioned (digits, strings, lists)

Comment: Please provide a few sample input data and the way that same data should be output after processing in the new file so someone can also see if they are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Python but some pseudo code with regexes to help you out:

```
prefix = ''
for (find = regexfind(/"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)",([^\n]+)/gi)) {
  print prefix + 'if newstr==' + find[1].replace("\W", '') + ':'
  print '  return eval(' + find[2] + ')'
  prefix = 'el'
}
```

`\W` (capital! W) captures everything that isn't a-z, 0-9 or _ and replaces it with an empty string.

Visualization of the longer regex that gives you the 2 separate pieces you want:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nKXG9q1eM_P5d4-T)